# how to remove invisible tableview cell's downloaded image . in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, tags, uitableview

I want to remove downloaded image in invisible tableview cell when I scrolled tableview.

So I set a tag

```
- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 int row=(int)indexPath
 UITableViewCell *cell;
 cell=[self.gamesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 OneItemCell *cell1=(OneItemCell*) cell;   //custom cell

 cell1.imageview.tag= row+100;

 }
```

I set remove downloaded image when selected row is last row cell(=add cell).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
     if(row==nArrayCount)
   {

  if(row>19) 
  {

    for(int i=1;i<row-8;i++)
    {


        [[self.gamesTableView viewWithTag:i+100] removeFromSuperview]; 

    }
 }

}
```

but it is not working . because [[self.gamesTableView viewWithTag:i+100] is NULL.

another way I set a key to cell's imageView by NSMutableDictionary(=imageRemoveInProgress)

```
 - (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {                   .
                       .

        [imageRemoveInProgress setObject:cell1.imageView forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+100]];

   }



   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {                     .
                       .
    [[imageRemoveInProgress objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+100]] removeFromSuperview];

 }
```

it is not working too . because[[imageRemoveInProgress objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+100]] is NULL too.

[[imageRemoveInProgress objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+100]] has value in appImageDidLoad.

but In - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

it has NULL.

why do taged and seted key value cell's imageView become NULL?

how to remove tableViewcell's imageview?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact way, But I can provide a hint to do it

you can use something like this

NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

visiblePaths is an array of indexPaths of cells that are currently visible, you can check whether the cell for which you want to remove the image lies in this array or not.